# How to check that symbol is in range (or array)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check that symbol is in range?

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
var curr_symb = in_text[i];
if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.curr_symb) { ...}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method :

```
if (curr_symb.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) { ...}
```